# Python - HCF program is not giving correct results

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def hcf(a,b):
    while b>0:
        a,b=b,a%b
    return a

numbers=[]
n=int(input("How many numbers? "))
i=0
while i<n:
    j=int(input("Enter a number: "))
    numbers.append(j)
    i+=1
result=numbers[0]
numbers.remove(result)

for k in numbers:
    hcf(result,k)
print(result)
```

Pls help in correcting this. When I give numbers as 2,3,4 it gives HCF=2. What should I do?
BTW: This is my first post.

Answer (score 0):

The second-last line should be `result = hcf(result,k)`

You are not updating the "result" after each number